# Pintrest-like grid

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

I am  looking for a way (jQuery plugin perhaps) to create a grid of variable height, fixed width divs. Something used in Pintrest.com for those of you familiar. Using inline elements or inline-block would cause gaps. It appears pintrest.com uses absolute positioning, put I'm lokking for a way to detect size and align elements accordingly.

http://pinterest.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Masonry is a good place to look for something more off the shelf - http://masonry.desandro.com/.  There's also a quora thread on the topic - http://b.qr.ae/wcGASb